# Refresh pivots doenst appear error

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code:

```
Sub Atualiza_pivots()

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

I do simple code that refresh all the pivots in the workbook, but if some pivot doenst refresh, it doesnt appear to me, so, I dont know when its getting a error. I try to make another code but it keep doesnt appear.

```
Sub Atualiza_pivots()

On Error GoTo Err

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

Exit Sub

Err: MsgBox "Há pivots com erro, verifique."

End Sub
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RefreshAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838648%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method only works if the BackgroundQuery is set to True, try this to loop through each table and refresh it manually:

```
Sub Refresher()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim pvt As PivotTable

For Each wks In Worksheets
    For Each pvt In wks.PivotTables
        If pvt.PivotCache.BackgroundQuery = False Then
            pvt.PivotCache.BackgroundQuery = True
            pvt.RefreshTable
            pvt.PivotCache.BackgroundQuery = False
        Else
            pvt.RefreshTable
        End If
    Next pvt
Next wks

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for the help, but I do another one that runs perfect to me

Answer (score 0):

Thx for the help D_Zab

```
Sub Atualiza_pivots()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim pvt As PivotTable

For Each wks In Worksheets
    For Each pvt In wks.PivotTables
            On Error GoTo Err
            pvt.PivotCache.Refresh
    Next pvt
Next wks
Exit Sub
Err: MsgBox pvt & " com erro."
End Sub
```